# Updating user inputs based on prompts C

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, debugging, output

The code down below reads the inputs of the user and if the the `input` given by the user is between
1 and 9 either the `playerselect` number `k` is updated to 1 or 2. If the `input` is out of bounds the `input` is re-prompted to the user. However there is a problem where after 2 prompts the `k` value is updated. Instead of code resulting in `Player 1 input` twice it should be `Player 1 input` and then `Player 2 input`.

```
int main(void)
{
    char playerSelect[][2] = {"1", "2"};

    int k=0;

    for(int i=1; i <= 18; i++){
        printf("\nPlayer %s input:", playerSelect[k]);
        scanf("%d",&input);
        if ((i % 2 == 0) && (1<= input <= 9)){k = 0;}
        else if ((i % 2 == 1) && (1<= input <= 9)){k = 1;}
        else {printf("Input out of bounds please input again");}
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Player 1 input:10
Input out of bounds please input again
Player 1 input:2

Player 1 input:2

Player 2 input:4
```

Wanted Output

```
Player 1 input:10
Input out of bounds please input again
Player 1 input:2

Player 2 input:2

Player 1 input:4
```

Comment: `k` is used uninitialized.

Comment: @alex01011 I don't think i understand

Comment: In your `printf("\nPlayer %s input:", playerSelect[k]);`, what is the value of `k` in the first iteration?

Comment: change `int k;` to `int k = 0;` .

Comment: that does not resolve the problem unfortunately but thank you I have updated the code

Comment: Note that the condition `(1 <= input <= 9)` does not do what you want.  It is parsed as `((1 <= input) <= 9)`, and `1 <= input` will produce either 0 or 1, both of which are less than 9, so the condition will always be true.  This isn't what you want.  You have to write `(1 <= input && input <= 9)` to get the result you're expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well each time an *out of bounds* input is given, you have to loop until you get a correct one, then update the `k` value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int input = 0, k = 0;
  char playerSelect[][2] = {"1", "2"};

  for (int i = 1; i <= 18; i++)
  {
    printf("\nPlayer %s input: ", playerSelect[k]);

    scanf("%d", &input);

    while (input > 9 || input < 1)
    {
      puts("Input out of bounds please input again");
      
      printf("\nPlayer %s input: ", playerSelect[k]);

      scanf("%d", &input);
    }

    k = ((i % 2 == 0) ? 0 : 1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```